# Switched indices in the second constructor, Matrix3D. For instance, why is n[0][1] = n10?

Tags: c++, 3d

I'm new to 3d game programming. I am reading Eric Lengyel's Foundations of Game Engine Development Volume 1 and I'm puzzled why he switched the indices in one of the Matrix3D constructors. For instance, n[0][1] = n10. Could this be to make matrix multiplication easier? Or is there another reason? Thank you.

```
public: 

   Matrix3D() = default; 
 
   Matrix3D(float n00, float n01, float n02,  float n10, float n11, float n12,  float n20, float n21, float n22)  {  n[0][0] = n00; n[0][1] = n10; n[0][2] = n20;  n[1][0] = n01; n[1][1] = n11; n[1][2] = n21;  n[2][0] = n02; n[2][1] = n12; n[2][2] = n22;  }  

   Matrix3D(const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b, const Vector3D& c)  {  n[0][0] = a.x; n[0][1] = a.y; n[0][2] = a.z;  n[1][0] = b.x; n[1][1] = b.y; n[1][2] = b.z;  n[2][0] = c.x; n[2][1] = c.y; n[2][2] = c.z;  }
```

Comment: I guess, to account [row-major vs col-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) differences. This is just a convention.

Comment: Evg, thank you, I thought about that too. I think it would have been helpful for the author to post a comment as to why this was done, but, that's just me...

Comment: The author explains this is a column major storage choice he made on page 14 as you quote in you comment below. As explained there, it provides efficient storage/extraction of vectors as columns of the matrix.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is not a row major vs column major issue.

Row maj vs col maj merely specifies whether the matrix rows are treated as entire vectors or whether the columns are treated as vector quantities. I believe this is an error in the API, since the constructor parameters are structured in a way that implies each parameter corresponds to a specific matrix element.

In a coherent math library, the matrix elements provided to the constructor should be expected to follow the convention of the API unless explicitly specified by the constructor. If i provide ‘5’ for the n01 parameter,i should expect m[0][1] to be 5, unless some documentation makes it extremely clear that this is not the case. This is an extremely important distinction in practice, as this could introduce confusing issues when importing certain types of data from modeling or animation programs.

I suggest examining the book’s concatenation operator or copy constructor if provided. Double check that the convention they introduced is repeated in the constructor and that multiplication follows proper matrix math conventions

Comment: Jon, thank you, and what you stated: "I believe this is an error in the API, since the constructor parameters are structured in a way that implies each parameter corresponds to a specific matrix element." I wonder if the author did make an error, since wouldn't it make more sense to have n[1][0] = n10? I've never seen code done like this before. Makes it confusing...to me, anyway...I wish the author had put comments next to the code for a helpful explanation as to why it's done...text in the book doesn't explain much...

Comment: @marcy_w Yes, i agree with your conclusions and would be hesitant to design a math library in this way, regardless. I suggest taking the book with a grain of salt, and look to open source libraries like GLM for more usable examples. A well planned math library should allow one to specify or switch the row vs col major convention, since openGL and Direct X are notoriously opposite in this respect.

Comment: Jon, thank you again. The author gives an explanation on pg 14, but it doesn't seem adequate, or wise, to me: "In order to implement column-major storage order in a two-dimensional array,  we need to make the first array index the column number and the second array  index the row number...so instead of allowing direct access to the matrix entries, we make  those private and provide overloaded parentheses operators that take two indices  in the familiar row-column order." Also, what are you referring to with GLM?

Comment: GLM is the openGL math library, it’s open source and reasonably performant so it’s an excellent introduction and example of an API that people actively use. That certainly is one way to structure your library if you and a few others are the only ones using it. In practice, and especially in game development (i am a professional physics programmer), i can tell you that people want and use matrix accessors regularly. That explanation seems like a silly solution to the problem, and you will see by examining other libraries that this is not a generally accepted solution. Eigen library is good too.

Comment: https://github.com/g-truc/glm is the github for GLM, they also have a decent documentation website as well

Comment: Jon, thank you again for your help. I checked out the GLM link, looks great. But honestly, I want to create my own graphics engine, and produce all the needed math methods/functions myself. Do you know a good book/website that can get me started? I thought E. Lengyel was the answer, but now not so sure...

Comment: Yeah, i prefer David Eberly’s books for things like this- Specifically his books like 3D Game Engine Architecture, Game Physics, and my personal favorite, Geometric Tools for Computer Graphics. All of these books demonstrate how to design a practical math library for use in games and physics. The last book provides a true wealth of information for any obscure or straight-forward geometric task that you may want to tackle for your custom engine, even his own take on the Polyhedral Mass Properties algorithm.

Comment: Jon, thank you and I will check them out! Really appreciate all your help :-)

Comment: There is no error in the api, and yes the documentation on p 14 will set user expectations straight, m(i,j) is stored in m[j][i], and you cannot access m[i][j] directly as they are private.